# Using ggplot to plot a customizable table of data

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

This idea has been spurred by this work at Five Thirty Eight.

[image]

I'm not entirely sure that they used R, but the chart appears in a similar fashion to their other data viz. I looked around here, but couldn't find anything directly relating to this.

Is this kind of plot possible using `ggplot`?

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: How would one begin to make a chart like this? Perhaps by having the data or a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I doubt they used ggplot2 to create this table. While potentially possible, it’s much easier to just format such a table using other tools (Brew, Markdown, some other LaTeX/HTML processor).

Comment: Thanks @KonradRudolph. I didn't know if there was another `ggplot` package add-on that made this kind of work possible or if they just used something else. 

@bouncyball Obviously my question is 'How would one begin to make a chart like this?'. I'm asking that question. I don't have the data, I'm just wondering if it's possible. If this isn't the correct place for that kind of question, I apologize. Could you point me in the right direction then?

Comment: @medavis6 If you find an answer to your question, based on the guidance you are getting, please post as an answer with a small subset of data.  I suspect it will be useful for a number of people.

Answer (score 0):

They do use R but their ggplot2 theme is semi-proprietary and they don't say what they use.  People have attempted to recreate the theme

https://github.com/jrnold/ggthemes

After the graphs are created it then goes through an illustrative step to bring graphs together and make them more of a story.